# Unable to embed second view controller on top of first view controller

Tags: ios

Im using the following code to show first view controller on top of a second view controller just like a dialog.

```
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
viewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
viewController.view.alpha = 0;
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
 {
     viewController.view.alpha = 1;
 }
                 completion:nil];
```

But the second view controller is not visible...How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: try `bringSubviewToFront` for `viewController.view`

Comment: it is not working bro

Comment: make sure childViewController(i.e. viewController) is not same as current view controller, and you're not adding it in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear etc.

Comment: Could you share `self` and `viewController` object's types?

Comment: Il you create the viewcontroller using UIViewcontroller(), it shows an empty vc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be where you mistake the code, I have write a demo for that:
I write two controller like this:

In `vc1`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initUI];
}

#pragma mark - init

- (void)initUI {

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

A) If use storyboard, init vc2 like this :
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 ViewController2 *vc2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

B)If use code ,init vc2 like this:
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];


[self addChildViewController:vc2];
vc2.view.frame = self.view.bounds
[self.view addSubview:vc2.view];
vc2.view.alpha = 0;
[vc2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
     {
         vc2.view.alpha = 1;
     }
                 completion:nil];
}

@end
```

In `vc2`:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

}
```

Comment: @user32231234124  I have said somewhere must write wrong.  please follow my code, you take a new project, have 2 `vc`, and copy my code to `vc1` and `vc2`, test this then reply.

Comment: i tried it...since Im having the view controllers in the same story board, i need to instantiate it over there for all views to be visible else the sub views wont be visible

Comment: @user31231234124  I have edit my answer, in stroyboard you should init vc2 like this:UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];`
2. Try  `viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;`
3. Do check if you have instantiate `viewController` properly.

Comment: I have tried your code, it works perfectly for me. Show me how you instantiate second viewcontroller?

Comment: I'm guessing Second ViewController is not instantiated properly.